# Remote web site day and month reverse when less than day 12 in Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-office, office-interop

Local machine visual studio day and month are normal in format dd/mm/yyyy.
But after deployed to remote web site, saved Excel using C#, less than day 12, become mm/dd/yyyy.

Actually the code is to get data into Excel from stored procedure which do pivot table

The way i save date to cell is

```
oSheet.Cells[currentline, i + 1] = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(reader[i].ToString()));

while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (reader[i] != System.DBNull.Value)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                oSheet.Cells[currentline, i + 1] = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(reader[i].ToString()));

            }
            else
                oSheet.Cells[currentline, i + 1] = reader[i].ToString();
        }
    }
    currentline = currentline + 1;
}
reader.Close();

        <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
        publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c"
        culture="neutral" />
        <publisherPolicy apply="yes" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="12.0.0.0"
        newVersion="11.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: Don't ever use Office Interop from an ASP.NET application. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score 0):

i solved after i add
UICulture="en" Culture="en-GB" in aspx

Comment: I remember that i meet date error in other cases which is also solved by adding UICulture="en" Culture="en-GB", it is safe using UICulture="en" Culture="en-GB"